# Junit Test cases for Spring MVC controller to check @PathVariable parameters in @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have following controller code for which I have to write Junit test case.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/cookbooks/{cookbook}/{version:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> getCookBookDetails(@PathVariable String cookbook, @PathVariable String version) {

        return proxyController.getCookBookDetails(cookbook, version);

    }
```

I'm writing the Junit test case for the same as

```
@Test
public void getCookBookDetailsSuccessTest() throws Exception {
    String cookbook = "{" + "\"cookbook\":{"
            + "\"version\": \"maven-1.1.0\","
            + "\"cookbook_name\": \"maven\"}"  + "}";

    when(proxyController.getCookBooks()).thenReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<String>(cookbook, new HttpHeaders(),
                    HttpStatus.OK));
    mockMvc.perform(get("/managment/cookbooks")
            .param("cookbook", "maven")
            .param("version", "1.1.0"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
}
```

Here I want to test the params passed in rest url path variable with the json sent in ResponEntity.

Tried to do so with

```
mockMvc.perform(
                get("/managment/cookbooks").param("cookbook", "maven").param(
                        "version", "1.1.0"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$cookbook[0]['cookbook_name']", is(cookbook)));
```

But its giving error as 

java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.List

Can anyone please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is this bug of json-path: https://code.google.com/p/json-path/issues/detail?id=24 Try to use json-path 0.9.

Comment: thanks a lot. the issue was with json-path version. one doubt, can we pass the param value in Matcher like param.getValue() or something ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. Maybe you could create a new question and provide some details.